# MongoParseError: Unescaped slash in userinfo section

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was trying to connect to MongoDB but i got the MongoParseError: Unescaped slash in userinfo section. Please help me :)

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(express.json());

//DB Config
const db = require('.np/config/keys').mongoURI;   

//Connect to Mongo
mongoose
    .connect(db,{useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    const port = process.env.port || 5000;

    app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server Started on port 5000'));
```

Comment: The error indicates a problem parsing the URL, buy you haven't shown us what that is.

Answer (score 6):

This happens due to the URL encoding problem. So all you need is encode into percentage encoding.
MongoDB official doc says

> If the username or password includes the at sign @, colon :, slash /, or the percent sign % character, use percent

I had a password like this `<password/>` and so I used a percentage encoding tool to encode and the result was like this `%3Cpassword%2F%3E`

online tool that I used : [url-encode-decode](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

NOTE : `<password%2F>` result will be the same as `%3Cpassword%2F%3E`

Answer (score 0):

While encoding might very likely be your problem, as @bodganoff answered, make sure the strings you are using in your database connection configuration are correct. In my case, after commenting the variables by mistake, the string was not formed properly, so make sure you double check what the strings are outputting and then you can fix it accordingly.